# Update content of list based of another id list by Stream

Tags: java, android, list, filter, java-stream

I'm trying to update the content of objects in the list of A if that object's id found in the list of B. This is my code and all thing works like a charm:

**listA: list of messages, for example with a length of 100**
**listB: string list of some messages Id which read by the user, for example with a length of 5**

```
Stream.of(messageList).filter(message-> {
        Optional<String> first = Stream.of(readMessageIdList)
                                       .filter(readMessageId-> readMessageId.equalsIgnoreCase(message.getId()))
                                       .findFirst();

        first.ifPresent(readMessageId-> message.setRead(true));
        return true;// return true intentionally, because I want don't filter my original messageList
        }).toList();
```

This code change `read` value from `message` object in listA if that `id` found in listB.

Now my question is: What is the best practice of this scenario? I know this is not best practice, because I create a stream for each message object (in this example 100 times).

*I use from [annimon](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) stream library.*

Comment: What are `readMessageIdList` and `readMessageIdList`?

Comment: @Naman both are the same : ), list of message's Id which read by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice - use Maps/Sets instead. LinkedHashMap will allow you to directly lookup (in O(1)) whether a messageId is present in another list holding messageIds, and will maintain the order of messages.